# Error 500 HTTP Request with body data length bigger than 100MB on C# API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0, http-status-code-500

We have developed an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API in C# created through a Visual Studio template.

It has been running for years and we have never had any performance issues. Until recently, we haven't had to deal with large HTTP requests, so we have improved the API configuration to allow requests larger than 2GB.

We have modified the Web.config of the application as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
     <webServices>
       <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
     </webServices>
   </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, we started to be able to receive requests larger than the 30MB that .NET web applications have by default without any problem, but, when these requests exceed approximately 100 MB, the application returns a 500 error.

The API is composed of 4 layers:

1. Security
2. Controller
3. Service
4. Repository

The issue is that I have tried to send data over 100MB and I have been able to verify that they reach layer 2 and 3 (layer 1 only manages user security) but when they are going to pass the data from layer 3 to layer 4, the application returns a 500 error.

The curious thing about this is that layers 3 and 4 are DLLs, they are not web projects where you can configure a request size limit.

The API is published in Azure and we think it's a memory problem, but, by increasing the API scaling and increasing the RAM and CPU, the same problem keeps happening.

Has anyone encountered something like this? Any possible solution?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You should check your logs to determine what causes an exception (in Layer 4 as you describe) which results in a HTTP status code 500 (internal server error) being returned. It sounds like you have an issue in your data access which isn't related to asp.net or Azure.

Comment: Many things may happen, firstly i was thinking bout RAM too, but it may be any problem, for example: problem with accessing data from multiple threads.
Without knowing what's in that layers exactly, its hard to tell what is going on.
As someone said, check details of error 500, if you have proper error handling, you should see a reason of that error.

Comment: You should enable and configure Application Insights. In that case the exception inclusive StackTrace will be recorded their. That's the only way (I can think of) to track down the root cause of the problem. Everything else is wild guessing.

Comment: There's no information on the error or the application itself. `4 layers` means nothing. Uploading 100MB can fail simply due to network issues or timeouts. Or it could be that inefficient database code is causing timeouts. Or you have some other exception which should appear in the application's logs

Comment: Is the entire file held in memory for example? A 100MB buffer is very big and there may not be enough memory to allocate such a huge buffer after a while. Writing 100MB to the database at once is slow too and can cause timeouts. Those are coding/design problems and increasing RAM or CPU will only cover them up. You need to find out what's wrong to begin with, by checking the logs. Or add logging if it's missing. Instead of keeping large files in memory, save them to a temporary file on disk, or Blob storage.

Comment: What does `Repository` mean too? Are you trying to load a 100MB into a relational database? Why? Which database? Some databases offer stream access for large objects, some don't. Sending 100MB as a single `varbinary` parameter is always a bad idea. Assuming there's a valid reason to store 100MB in a database (a rare case), you could load the data using the ADO.NET provider's streaming features. If you use a managed Azure database there may be ways to import directly from Blob storage